# How can I export a VM as OVA with VMware Workstation?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

How can I export a VM as an OVA using VMware Workstation 16 Pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What confused me was that VMware Workstation 16 Pro's file browser on Windows showed only one file format output:
[image]

What I had to do was edit the **File name** value and change the `.ovf` to `.ova`, and then click **Save**.

So in full, the steps are:

1. Select the VM you want to export
2. In the menu bar, chose **File > Export to OVF...**
3. Browse to the directory you want to export to
4. Edit the **File name** value and change the `.ovf` to `.ova`
5. Click the **Save** button
6. Wait for the export to complete (note that, at least on VMware Workstation 16 Pro, there is no dialog message to notify you that the export has completed)

Answer (score 2):

Here, [Export a Virtual Machine to OVF Format](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Fusion/12/com.vmware.fusion.using.doc/GUID-16E390B1-829D-4289-8442-270A474C106A.html), you can find official documentation how:

> 1. Select the virtual machine and select **File** > **Export to OVF**.
> 2. Enter a name for the OVF file and specify a directory in which to save it.
> 3. Specify whether to export the virtual machine as an OVF, a folder with separate files, or as an OVA, a single-file archive.
> 4. Click **Export** to start the OVF export process.
>
>    The export process can take several minutes. A status bar indicates the progress of the export process.

Comment: Your answer almost works, but if you do not also change the file extension from `.ovf` to `.ova`, then you will not get an OVA file, which is what I specify I want in my question. You do not explicitly mention this necessary detail in your answer.